# BottomSheet with AngularFire Phone Auth incorrect behavior

Tags: angular, angular-material

Here's my intended workflow:

- User submits form in registration component
- Phone authentication is triggered (this comes with recaptcha)
- A bottomsheet is brought up with a field to enter the verification code.
- On bottomsheet dismiss, verification code is passed to registration component, which then proceeds to verify the code, and then continues with registration logic.

The above, here's the current code.

```
  onSubmit(formData) {
    firebase
      .auth()
      // send text message to user
      .signInWithPhoneNumber(formData.phone, this.recaptchaVerifier)
      .then(confirmationResult => {
        // bring up bottomsheet
        const dialogRef = this.bottomSheet.open(VerifyphoneComponent, {
          disableClose: true,
          closeOnNavigation: true
        });

        dialogRef.afterDismissed().subscribe(result => {
          console.log(result);
          if (result) {
            confirmationResult.confirm(result).then(good => {
              console.log(good);
              // call the registeration part
              this.af.auth
                .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                  formData.email,
                  formData.password
                )
                .then(res => {...})
                .catch(err => {
                  this.busy = false;
                  this.snack.open(err.message, "Close");
                  console.log(err);
                });
            });
          } else {
            this.busy = false;
            this.snack.open(
              "Phone verification couldn't happen. Try again",
              "Close"
            );
          }
        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.snack.open(err.message, "Close");
      });
  }
```

Here's how the recaptcha is initialized (assuming it matters)

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
      "recaptcha-container",
      {
        size: "invisible"
      }
    );
  }
```

This is the verify component

```
export class VerifyphoneComponent implements OnInit {
  code: string;
  isBusy: boolean;

  constructor(private bottomSheetRef: MatBottomSheetRef<VerifyphoneComponent>) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onSubmit(code) {
    this.isBusy = true;
    this.bottomSheetRef.dismiss(code);
  }
}
```

With the above, here's what currently happens

- User submits form
- Bottomsheet comes up as expect, **but**
- When the `onSubmit()` is called,

1) The bottomsheet doesn't close automatically. If the `disableClose` optional param is set to false, then clicking outside the bottomsheet (on the backdrop) then closes the bottomsheet immediately, and proceeds to run the rest of the code.

2) Otherwise, the bottomsheet just remains stuck, and nothing happens.

Am I using the bottomsheet wrongly?

**Edit**

Added my issue in a repo: https://github.com/seanmavley/for-debugging

Comment: are you certain that the `onSubmit` is called on the verify component

Comment: @c_ogoo yes. `onSubmit` is called.

Comment: Are you able to recreate the problem on stackblitz, dont see any obvious issues here

Comment: @c_ogoo I'll do that soon. thanks

Comment: @C_Ogoo couldn't get the stackblitz up, but I just replicated what the issue is and have it in this repo: https://github.com/seanmavley/for-debugging

Comment: add a bounty for this?

Comment: I got the code to run and the bottom sheet works as expexted. I commented out the `firebase.auth`

Comment: what are the errors in your console?

Comment: Is there any errors in your console?

Comment: Nope. I don't get any errors in my console.